# Deleting all lines before a specific line python

Tags: python, file

I have a file-

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
Fifth Line
Sixth Line
```

Now I want to write the contents of the file after the fourth line.
therefore the new file would be-

```
Fifth Line
Sixth Line
```

My attempt-

```
cnt=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentdir):
    for name in files:



        f = open(root+"/"+name,'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        f = open(os.path.join(root, name),"w")
        for line in lines:
            cnt+=1 
            if line =="fourth Line"+"\n":
                break:
        f.seek(cnt)
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

Comment: You've over-complicated it and it will only write out the fourth line. But what is your question?

Comment: Your example deals with a single file, but your code iterates through a directory structure.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: The basic logic is to *skip* lines until you encounter your "trigger" line.  Then you enter another loop that simply writes the remainder of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(currentdir):
    for name in files:
        with open(os.path.join(path, name)) as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        pos = data.index("Fourth Line\n")
        with open(os.path.join(path, name), 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(data[pos:])
```

Comment: I am getting this error-AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find' on this line-pos = data.find("*edges\n")

Comment: @ubuntu_noob oops, typo - fixed now

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the lines in a file, slice the array, and then write them back in:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.write(lines[5:])
```

If you wanted to you could read and write in separate `with` blocks, or whatever else.

Comment: Its not necessary that the line would be the fourth one....it is a line

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file lines to a list, and after split the list keeping only the lines you want and saving on the file. Example, if you want the content after the 4th line:

```
f = open("file.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
lines = lines[4:]
f = open("file.txt", 'w')
f.write(lines)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always place a counter in loop, and start writing the second file when counter reaches 4. Something like:

```
with open('a', 'w') as a, open('b', 'w') as b:
do_something()
```

or:

```
f1 = open(path, 'w')
f1.write(data)
f1.close()
counter += 1
if counter >= 4:
f2 = open(path, 'w')
f2.write(data)
f2.close()
```